# Can't find node inside of Modal - test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Not being able to render and test a click event inside of a Modal.
How can I access the content inside of a modal as well

Using Jest and Enzyme for React js

Here is my test file:

```
 beforeEach(() => wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter keyLength={0}><ClassName    

it('Test Request Button Close on Modal', () => {
 baseProps.onClick.mockClear();
 wrapper.find('ClassName').setState({ 
    modalOpen:true,
  })
wrapper.update()
wrapper.find('ClassName').find('#close-btn').simulate('click')
});
```

Here is the file.js
Get the following message:  Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.modalOpen} style={customStyles}>
 <div className='request-response-modal'>
  <button title='Close' className='request-button-close' id='close-btn'  onClick={this.toggleModal}>
```

Comment: What is Modal? Is it your component?

Comment: nope, i have the component and then a Modal under render - modal popup window . Im notable to render anything inside of it

Comment: I'm having the same problem. :(

Comment: @TiggerToo i was able to figure out